# DialogFlow CX flow not routing to next page when using page parameter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx

I have a  page that has an entry fulfillment and route to another page. The intent that maps to the route has training phrases for @sys.number variable which map to parameter id: number. I also have a page parameter my_variable of type sys.number. The Route condition is set to Match at least one rule.

When I test this in the test agent, my input gets mapped to the correct parameter. However, the test agent does not proceed to the next page. If I enter input a second time, then I am routed to the next page. How can I achieve being routed to the next page after my first initial input?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following condition resolves my issue.

[image]